# Setting an external editor in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

Vimperator has a very convenient function — using an external editor for filling text fields. By default it uses GVim but I would like to use Gedit or Vim. I tried to add to `~/.vimperatorrc` the following lines but without result (the editors is opened but the typed text isn't added to text fields):

```
:set editor=gedit

:set editor="gnome-terminal -e vim"
```

How can I set an external editor for filling text fields in Vimperator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely a mystery to me why the things you tried don't work when placed in .vimperatorrc (though they don't work for me either). It's very strange. But this seems to work:

`autocmd LocationChange .* :set editor="gedit"`

It takes effect even with the first page that loads.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I start the browser, go to page with a web-form, focus a text field, press _Ctrl+i_, Gedit starts with the _vimperator-<base\_url>-<number>.tmp_ page opened, I start to type text, save it, close the editor and that's all, nothing happens, the text feild is empty.

Comment: Sorry, this seems like an unrelated bug. It works for me just fine. (Vimperator 2.3.1 on Firefox 3.6.8 on Arch Linux.)

Comment: It starts working. It seems, it has to restart X-es. Thanks for help, **frabjous**.

Answer (score 2):

To use `vim` through `gnome-terminal` v3.4.1.1, I had to tell `gnome-terminal` to not fork a process but block:

In ~/.vimperatorrc:

```
:set editor="gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x vim"
```

or better yet, to have your ~/.bashrc loaded (e.g. in case it conditionally sets TERM or other environment) before launching vim, and to pass some setup commands to vim (e.g. a command ExtEditor defined in ~/.vimrc that e.g. adjusts the linbreak setting):

```
:set editor="gnome-terminal --maximize --disable-factory -x bash -ic 'vim -c ExtEditor $0'"
```

Comment: I discovered this feature recently. This option allowed me to stop using GVim completely.

Comment: GNOME developers have removed the `--disable-factory` option from `gnome-terminal`, unfortunately. Any workaround?

Comment: Doesn't work any more. `GNOME Terminal 3.14.2`, running `gnome-terminal --disable-factory -e vim; echo foo` prints `foo` immediately and doesn't wait for `gnome-terminal` to close, hence, it forked.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was

```
:set editor="urxvt -e vim"
```

Works like a charm. Of course you have to be using vim from the urxvt terminal.

Comment: I get "Error: no file name" when I try to save the file using this method