# Vimperator. Setting an external editor in Windows XP

Tags: windows, gvim, vimperator

This should be easy but I just cannot seem to get it working despite searching for answers, so I turn to you fine ladies and gentlemen. This is what my C:\Documents and Settings\user_vimperatorrc file looks like:

```
set "editor=C:\\bin\\gvim.exe -f"
```

The gvim executable does exist there and it runs. When in the text area I type C-i and I get this error:

```
Command not found: C:bingvim.exe
```

I have tried a bunch of other things but none have worked. Can someone share with me how you got it working in windows?

Comment: Have you tried triple or quadruple backslashes (or even single ones)?

Comment: Your quotation mark placement is weird. Have you tried either `set editor="C:\\bin\\gvim.exe -f"` or `set editor='C:\bin\gvim.exe -f'`? I don't use Windows, but just using set editor in my .vimperatorrc didn't work for me. I had to do what I described in this topic: http://superuser.com/questions/186782/vimperator-setting-an-external-editor/186815#186815

Comment: I will try these suggestions when I get back to that computer. In the mean time if anyone has a real working example I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: set editor='C:\\bin\\gvim.exe -f'  finally worked.

Comment: @stephenmm, Can you put that as an answer and mark it as accepted so that this question doesn't show up as unresolved?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution I came up with:

```
set editor='C:\\bin\\gvim.exe -f'
```

Comment: For reference, in pentadactyl I'm using `set editor='C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe -f +<line> +"sil! call cursor(0, <column>)" <file>'`

Answer (score 6):

This is what finally worked for me in Windows 7 after trying TONS of different escaping possibilities. Turns out you need `/` for the path separator, and `\\` before a space:

```
set editor="C:/Program\\ Files\\ (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe"
```

Comment: but of course... *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue. On the Windows XP SP3 machine that I am forced to deal with, I added this line:

```
set editor='C:\\Program\ Files\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe -f'
```

To this file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\dotancohen\_vimperatorrc
```

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows 7 machine, I added the directory containing the `gvim.exe` executable (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74` in my case) to the PATH environmental variable, so typing `gvim` in a DOS box worked.

I then restarted Firefox, and all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Win8 required

```
:set editor="C:/Program\\ Files/vim/vim74/gvim.exe\ -f"
```