# How to make Vimperator work with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: vim, sublime-text-2, vimperator

I am using Firefox & add-in Vimperator and want to use Sublime to edit textareas.

Currently when I focus textarea and press CTRL+i I get "Command not found: gvim". I already have Sublime installed and would love to use it if possible for editing text in textareas. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: When you focus using what program? Using what operating system (both sublime and vim are cross platform)?

Comment: You may want to consider using wasavi instead, though it might not be as feature-rich as you want.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm typing this from within the Sublime Text 2 editor... it proved to be harder than I expected.

You need to go to: c:\Users\$USERNAME$_vimperatorrc and enter this line:

```
set editor='d:\\Portable\\Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64\\sublime_text.exe -f'
```

Make sure to escape both \ and SPACE like you can see from example. This thread helped: [Vimperator. Setting an external editor in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/189971/vimperator-setting-an-external-editor-in-windows-xp?lq=1)